# Dúvida em relação a links permanentes para postagens

Tags: php, htaccess, desempenho

Em meu projeto, os usuário podem fazer postagens, e, gostaria que cada postagem tivesse um link permanente para poder ser acessada separadamente.

No que eu já pensei:

1. Criar um arquivo *postagem.php* que receberia o id da postagem via GET e exibiria os dados, também poderia ser criado uma condição no .htaccess para deixar a URL mais amigável (porém, estou com receio desse método por questões de segurança).
2. Criar uma pasta "posts" e, dentro dela, criar uma pasta para cada postagem com sua id, e, dentro dela, ter uma *index.php* que exibiria os dados. Porém acredito que assim consumiria muito espaço no servidor.

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso? Lembrando que, gostaria de fazer algo como "/posts/idcriptografada/" para o link.

**Obrigado!**

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54276/discussion-on-question-by-igor-duvida-em-relacao-a-links-permanentes-para-postag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você está tentando fazer se chama "slugify", que é criar um slug, como um identificador único para um recurso (o post, no caso). Um bom exemplo é a própria URL para essa sua questão aqui no Stackoverflow.  stackoverflow.com/questions/59475/***dúvida-em-relação-a-links-permanentes-para-postagens*** - o slug além de ser um identificador legível para um recurso, ele ainda é completamente SEO amigável. O Google ama slugs.

Conheça mais sobre o assunto: [O que é Slug? E a importância de URLs amigáveis no Blog](http://www.ferramentasblog.com/2012/05/slug-importancia-de-urls-amigaveis-no-blog.html) - ignore "no Blog", isso se aplica a qualquer conteúdo.

## Estrutura inicial para slugs

Tenha uma coluna "slug" na tabela de posts, no seu banco de dados. Quando o post for criado, você gera o slug utilizando o título do post. Como estaremos criando um sistema simples de slugs, para evitar colisões é recomendado anexar o ID do post ou um identificador único, podendo ser o ID do usuário (e não há problema nenhum de segurança ao se colocar os Ids).

Por exemplo:

- Título: Como criar links permanentes?
- Slug: como-criar-links-permanentes-120 (120 = id do post no banco de dados)

## Como redirecionar links para posts

Se você tem sua aplicação estruturada usando MVC, você provavelmente já faz o bootstrap da sua aplicação em apenas um arquivo, provavelmente o index.php. Nesse caso você precisa de uma regra para que o Apache (ou nginx) reconheça os links e repasse os slugs para sua aplicação:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Para uma chamada como http://localhost/posts/como-criar-links-permanentes-120, o caminho junto do slug estará disponível em $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']:

```
[REQUEST_URI] => /posts/como-criar-links-permanentes-120
```

Porém, caso você não esteja estruturada em MVC, e utilize arquivos individuais para recursos, por exemplo: post.php, nada lhe impede de utilizar query string como links permanentes:

```
http://localhost/post.php?slug=como-criar-links-permanentes-120
```

Assim basta você pegar o slug em $_GET['slug'].

## Como criar slugs

As possibilidades são infinitas, mas deixo aqui alguns exemplos de funções:

Sem dependências externas ([fonte](https://gist.github.com/sgmurphy/3098978)):

```
function url_slug($str, $options = array()) {
    // Make sure string is in UTF-8 and strip invalid UTF-8 characters
    $str = mb_convert_encoding((string)$str, 'UTF-8', mb_list_encodings());

    $defaults = array(
        'delimiter' => '-',
        'limit' => null,
        'lowercase' => true,
        'replacements' => array(),
        'transliterate' => false,
    );

    // Merge options
    $options = array_merge($defaults, $options);

    $char_map = array(
        // Latin
        'À' => 'A', 'Á' => 'A', 'Â' => 'A', 'Ã' => 'A', 'Ä' => 'A', 'Å' => 'A', 'Æ' => 'AE', 'Ç' => 'C',
        'È' => 'E', 'É' => 'E', 'Ê' => 'E', 'Ë' => 'E', 'Ì' => 'I', 'Í' => 'I', 'Î' => 'I', 'Ï' => 'I',
        'Ð' => 'D', 'Ñ' => 'N', 'Ò' => 'O', 'Ó' => 'O', 'Ô' => 'O', 'Õ' => 'O', 'Ö' => 'O', 'Ő' => 'O',
        'Ø' => 'O', 'Ù' => 'U', 'Ú' => 'U', 'Û' => 'U', 'Ü' => 'U', 'Ű' => 'U', 'Ý' => 'Y', 'Þ' => 'TH',
        'ß' => 'ss',
        'à' => 'a', 'á' => 'a', 'â' => 'a', 'ã' => 'a', 'ä' => 'a', 'å' => 'a', 'æ' => 'ae', 'ç' => 'c',
        'è' => 'e', 'é' => 'e', 'ê' => 'e', 'ë' => 'e', 'ì' => 'i', 'í' => 'i', 'î' => 'i', 'ï' => 'i',
        'ð' => 'd', 'ñ' => 'n', 'ò' => 'o', 'ó' => 'o', 'ô' => 'o', 'õ' => 'o', 'ö' => 'o', 'ő' => 'o',
        'ø' => 'o', 'ù' => 'u', 'ú' => 'u', 'û' => 'u', 'ü' => 'u', 'ű' => 'u', 'ý' => 'y', 'þ' => 'th',
        'ÿ' => 'y',
        // Latin symbols
        '©' => '(c)',
        // Greek
        'Α' => 'A', 'Β' => 'B', 'Γ' => 'G', 'Δ' => 'D', 'Ε' => 'E', 'Ζ' => 'Z', 'Η' => 'H', 'Θ' => '8',
        'Ι' => 'I', 'Κ' => 'K', 'Λ' => 'L', 'Μ' => 'M', 'Ν' => 'N', 'Ξ' => '3', 'Ο' => 'O', 'Π' => 'P',
        'Ρ' => 'R', 'Σ' => 'S', 'Τ' => 'T', 'Υ' => 'Y', 'Φ' => 'F', 'Χ' => 'X', 'Ψ' => 'PS', 'Ω' => 'W',
        'Ά' => 'A', 'Έ' => 'E', 'Ί' => 'I', 'Ό' => 'O', 'Ύ' => 'Y', 'Ή' => 'H', 'Ώ' => 'W', 'Ϊ' => 'I',
        'Ϋ' => 'Y',
        'α' => 'a', 'β' => 'b', 'γ' => 'g', 'δ' => 'd', 'ε' => 'e', 'ζ' => 'z', 'η' => 'h', 'θ' => '8',
        'ι' => 'i', 'κ' => 'k', 'λ' => 'l', 'μ' => 'm', 'ν' => 'n', 'ξ' => '3', 'ο' => 'o', 'π' => 'p',
        'ρ' => 'r', 'σ' => 's', 'τ' => 't', 'υ' => 'y', 'φ' => 'f', 'χ' => 'x', 'ψ' => 'ps', 'ω' => 'w',
        'ά' => 'a', 'έ' => 'e', 'ί' => 'i', 'ό' => 'o', 'ύ' => 'y', 'ή' => 'h', 'ώ' => 'w', 'ς' => 's',
        'ϊ' => 'i', 'ΰ' => 'y', 'ϋ' => 'y', 'ΐ' => 'i',
        // Turkish
        'Ş' => 'S', 'İ' => 'I', 'Ç' => 'C', 'Ü' => 'U', 'Ö' => 'O', 'Ğ' => 'G',
        'ş' => 's', 'ı' => 'i', 'ç' => 'c', 'ü' => 'u', 'ö' => 'o', 'ğ' => 'g',
        // Russian
        'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V', 'Г' => 'G', 'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E', 'Ё' => 'Yo', 'Ж' => 'Zh',
        'З' => 'Z', 'И' => 'I', 'Й' => 'J', 'К' => 'K', 'Л' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N', 'О' => 'O',
        'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R', 'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T', 'У' => 'U', 'Ф' => 'F', 'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'C',
        'Ч' => 'Ch', 'Ш' => 'Sh', 'Щ' => 'Sh', 'Ъ' => '', 'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ь' => '', 'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'Yu',
        'Я' => 'Ya',
        'а' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e', 'ё' => 'yo', 'ж' => 'zh',
        'з' => 'z', 'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'j', 'к' => 'k', 'л' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n', 'о' => 'o',
        'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'с' => 's', 'т' => 't', 'у' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'c',
        'ч' => 'ch', 'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'sh', 'ъ' => '', 'ы' => 'y', 'ь' => '', 'э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'yu',
        'я' => 'ya',
        // Ukrainian
        'Є' => 'Ye', 'І' => 'I', 'Ї' => 'Yi', 'Ґ' => 'G',
        'є' => 'ye', 'і' => 'i', 'ї' => 'yi', 'ґ' => 'g',
        // Czech
        'Č' => 'C', 'Ď' => 'D', 'Ě' => 'E', 'Ň' => 'N', 'Ř' => 'R', 'Š' => 'S', 'Ť' => 'T', 'Ů' => 'U',
        'Ž' => 'Z',
        'č' => 'c', 'ď' => 'd', 'ě' => 'e', 'ň' => 'n', 'ř' => 'r', 'š' => 's', 'ť' => 't', 'ů' => 'u',
        'ž' => 'z',
        // Polish
        'Ą' => 'A', 'Ć' => 'C', 'Ę' => 'e', 'Ł' => 'L', 'Ń' => 'N', 'Ó' => 'o', 'Ś' => 'S', 'Ź' => 'Z',
        'Ż' => 'Z',
        'ą' => 'a', 'ć' => 'c', 'ę' => 'e', 'ł' => 'l', 'ń' => 'n', 'ó' => 'o', 'ś' => 's', 'ź' => 'z',
        'ż' => 'z',
        // Latvian
        'Ā' => 'A', 'Č' => 'C', 'Ē' => 'E', 'Ģ' => 'G', 'Ī' => 'i', 'Ķ' => 'k', 'Ļ' => 'L', 'Ņ' => 'N',
        'Š' => 'S', 'Ū' => 'u', 'Ž' => 'Z',
        'ā' => 'a', 'č' => 'c', 'ē' => 'e', 'ģ' => 'g', 'ī' => 'i', 'ķ' => 'k', 'ļ' => 'l', 'ņ' => 'n',
        'š' => 's', 'ū' => 'u', 'ž' => 'z'
    );

    // Make custom replacements
    $str = preg_replace(array_keys($options['replacements']), $options['replacements'], $str);

    // Transliterate characters to ASCII
    if ($options['transliterate']) {
        $str = str_replace(array_keys($char_map), $char_map, $str);
    }

    // Replace non-alphanumeric characters with our delimiter
    $str = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{Nd}]+/u', $options['delimiter'], $str);

    // Remove duplicate delimiters
    $str = preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote($options['delimiter'], '/') . '){2,}/', '$1', $str);

    // Truncate slug to max. characters
    $str = mb_substr($str, 0, ($options['limit'] ? $options['limit'] : mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8')), 'UTF-8');

    // Remove delimiter from ends
    $str = trim($str, $options['delimiter']);

    return $options['lowercase'] ? mb_strtolower($str, 'UTF-8') : $str;
}
```

Como usar:

```
echo url_slug("olá titulo do meu post", ['transliterate' => true]);
ola-titulo-do-meu-post
```

Ou uma função enxuta usando a biblioteca iconv ([fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string)):

```
function slugify($text)
{
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    return strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $text));
}

echo slugify("olá titulo do meu post");
// Resultado: ol-a-titulo-do-meu-post
```

## Informação Adicional

[Usando Links Permanentes](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Usando_Links_permanentes) (Wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um campo na tabela, e salvar sua id criptografada, ai quando você for pegar os dados do DB vc compara as duas, dessa maneira:

```
$idCriptografada = md5(1); // o id seria 1

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id_criptografado='".$idCriptografada."'");
```

Dessa maneira você conseguiria pegar os dados.

**OBS.:** usei o `md5()` como exeplo, pode usar qualquer outro método que você quiser.