# Buscar registro no MySQL sem usar ?id=id na URL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, get

galera, estou tentando não usar o $_GET[] no link, mas não estou conseguindo achar alguma forma para isso acontecer. Ou seja, em vez de "site.com/?post=nome noticia" ficar "site.com/nome-noticia". Já revirei fóruns e no Stack também atrás de uma solução, mas não encontrei nada sem que suma o "?post=" da URL.
O código atual é esse:

```
<?php
if(!@mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))
{
    die('ERRO NA CONEXÃO! --> '.mysql_error());
}
if(!mysql_select_db("site_novo"))
{
    die('NOME DB ERRADO--> '.mysql_error());
}
$video = $_GET['video'] ;
$videoId = $video;
$video_select = "SELECT * FROM video WHERE `id_video`='$video_select'";
$query = @mysql_query($video_select) or die (mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($query) <= 0) {
    echo 'ESSE VÍDEO NÃO EXISTE AINDA';
}else{
    $vd = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    include_once "../assets/include/head_video.php";
}?>
```

---

***RESOLUÇÃO***

```
<?php 
if(!@mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))
{
    die('ERRO NA CONEXÃO! --> '.mysql_error());
}
if(!mysql_select_db("site_novo"))
{
    die('NOME DB ERRADO--> '.mysql_error());
}
$video = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
$muda_path = explode('/', $video );
foreach( $muda_path as $video_link )
{
    $videoID = $video_link;
    $video_select = "SELECT * FROM video WHERE `id_video`='$videoID'";
    $query = @mysql_query($video_select) or die (mysql_error());
}?>
```

Comment: Qual o código de `head_video.php` ?

Comment: O que você precisa é implementar o sistema de URL amigaveis.
Dá uma olha neste post [URL Amigaveis conceito](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis) e uma exemplo mais completo. [Exemplo completo](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/criando-url-amigaveis-com-um-codigo-simples-e-funcional)

Comment: <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title><?php echo $vd['titulo_video']; ?> - Player </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="../assets/css/external_embed.css?v=2.25.5" />
  
</head>

Comment: Segue esse link do Stack en-us que foi solucionado. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722711/url-routing-regex-php

Comment: Na verdade eu falei errado, invés do código que colocou, qual o código, o `link`, que te levar a iniciar esses includes ?

Comment: Sem usar parâmetros, pode usar as variáveis $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] e $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] dependendo do contexto. Isto retorna o caminho da requisição. O único cuidado é fazer com que qualquer caminho seja atendido pelo mesmo PHP, para processar a informação. Alternativamente, se usar esta sintaxe, nem precisa fazer nada complexo:  example.com/news.php/eneadactilo-e-preso-tentando-sair-do-pais , aí bastam alguma das variáveis mencionadas.

Comment: @MagicHat é que pretendo usar em várias páginas, e ficar add o mesmo head em cada página não ajuda se precisar add ou tirar algum css. Esse é só a página do "embed".

Comment: @Bacco, tem algum exemplo em que eu possa me basear?

Comment: o exemplo é você salvar um arquivo como news.php apenas com esta linha: `<?php echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']; ` e acessá-lo como endereco.com/news.php/noticia-numero-doze, para ver como se comporta a variável. Uma vez que entenda como ela é preenchida, aí você faz a lógica para o seu select.

Comment: @Bacco estou explorando a `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];` aqui, criei um php chamado "teste" e troquei de `$video = $_GET['video'] ;` para `$video = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];`, mas ele está retornando "/" junto, vou tentar dar um explode na "/" para pegar só a ID.

Comment: @Bacco, @MagicHat, ficou assim   `<?php 
if(!@mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))
{
 die('oops connection problem ! --> '.mysql_error());
}
if(!mysql_select_db("site_novo"))
{
 die('oops database selection problem ! --> '.mysql_error());
}
$video = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
$palavras = explode('/', $video );
foreach( $palavras as $video_link )
{
 $videoId = $video_link;
 $leitura = "SELECT * FROM video WHERE `id_video`='$videoId'";
 $query = @mysql_query($leitura) or die (mysql_error());
}
?>` valeu galera!!

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/77846/28632